# Android/Java long math sometimes off by a small decimal

Tags: java, android, math, long-integer

I'm having a small issue that I cannot seem to figure out. I am getting the time in milliseconds from two calanders, subtracting them, and dividing the result to get the difference of the two calanders in days. When done repeatedly sometimes this math will be off by a small decimal, usually .0000001. Is there a way to remedy this? Note: I need to keep these numbers as a long value because they will get huge after a while.

Heres the code:

First I get the calander date's value in milliseconds...

```
    final long calendarOne = datePickerCalendar
             .getTimeInMillis();

    final long calendarTwo = actualCalendar
             .getTimeInMillis();
```

Then I subtract the two numbers...

```
    if(calendarOne > calendarTwo)
    {

         long differenceInMilliseconds = (long)
             (calendarOne) - (calendarTwo);

    }
```

The value of differenceInMilliseconds will vary as follows with no changes between the two calendars.

Correct number: 63417600000

Incorrect number: 63417599999

Incorrect number: 63417599997

The math comes up with the correct number most of the time but I can't figure out why there would be a discrepancy. Am I doing something wrong in my mathematics? Or is there a way to round longs?

Thanks for any help

Comment: What happens if you print out the values of `calendarOne` and `calendarTwo` along with the result? Do they appear correct or incorrect? Are you sure it's the math that's causing the error, and not the source?

Comment: You can't seriously be suggesting that long arithmetic doesn't work in Java. You have presented zero evidence that the two calendars are returning the same values. Not a real question.

Comment: Calendar one is created at xxxxxxxxx999 nanaseconds.  Calendar two is created at xxxxxxx001 nanoseconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you create `actualCalendar`, do `actualCalendar.set( MILLISECOND, 0 )`, also do the same on `datePickerCalendar` and you will ensure that any difference between the two will be at least a second.  Should fix your problem, since it's probably due to delay between creating the two calendars.

Comment: That did it! Thank you very much I didn't even consider it being an issue with the calendars.

Answer (score 3):

> The math comes up with the correct number most of the time but I can't figure out why there would be a discrepancy. Am I doing something wrong in my mathematics? Or is there a way to round longs?

No and no.  There is no rounding when you subtract one integer from another.

The probable cause is in the way the two calendar objects are being created.  I suspect that they are getting their initial values from the system clock, and that in some cases there is a large enough elapsed time between the respective creation times to be noticeable in the millisecond-level time values.